# python: regex match credit card starting with fixed letters

Tags: python, regex, string, numbers

I want to write a regex that matches the following credit card that starts with fixed letters, e.g,

```
examples = ['AU01 0000 1234 5678 9012 00', 'AU01 3200 1564 5678 9987 55']
```

I have written the following regex but it does not capture the letters 'AU'.

```
regex = r'(?:(\w*AU)[0-9]{4}\s){3}[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{16}|[0-9]{2}'
```

Comment: `^AU(?:\d\d \d\d){5}$` maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not matching 2 digits after AU, and when you repeat the 4 digits you can place the space before the digits.

```
^AU\d\d(?: \d{4}){4} \d\d$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BHRMnt/1)

Or you can use as suggested in the comments by @JvdV repeating 5 times a set of 4 numbers with a space in between:

```
^AU(?:\d\d \d\d){5}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rNUI6P/1)

Or when also allowing 20 digits with optional spaces in between:

```
^AU\d(?: ?\d){19}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BHRMnt/1)

Answer (score 1):

This expression will include the starting A and U once each and then look for 4 combinations of 4 digit numbers and then a combination of 2 digit number at the end:
`AU(\d{4}){4}(\d{2})`.

NOTE : You'll need to remove the spaces from the strings in order to match this expression.